# Angular - Browse route direct

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I need to browse a URL direct and pass a value, such as localhost:4200/vip/mycode, then this will direct to the default page.

I have the routing.module.ts set like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'enroll', component: EnrollComponent },
  { path: 'default', component: DefaultComponent },
  { path: 'aboutus', component: AboutusComponent },
  { path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent },
  { path: 'contactus', component: ContactusComponent },
  { path: 'vip/:code', component: VipComponent },

];
```

And the vip.component.ts file like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vip',
  templateUrl: './vip.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vip.component.css']
})
export class VipComponent implements OnInit {
  public code: string;
  public APIresult: any;
  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
  ) { 
    
    this._route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.code = params.code; 
      if (this.code != null) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('code', this.code);
        alert(this.code)
      }
    })
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

But I just cant make it work when browsing localhost:4200/vip/mycode

When I do, it just takes me to the default component.

Here is my app.component.ts:

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Website';
  
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ){  
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/default")
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When browse to /users/Jimmy, app constructor gets called, and it redirect to default. Removing this this.router.navigateByUrl("/default") should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should also add this to route array so that it get redirected to default.

> { path: '', redirectTo: 'default', pathMatch: 'full' },